# How to Xor on integer arrays in matlab

Tags: matlab, xor

i need a efficient way to XOR two array of integer numbers in matlab. For example:

```
A=[3,4,5,1,6,7,3];

B=[3,5,5,2,6,2,3];
```

the result for `C=Xor(A,B)` must be:

```
C=[0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
```

i need to run this many times on large arrays, so efficiency is very important.
thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you try [`bitxor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitxor.html)?

Comment: Shouldn't your result be `C=[0 1 0 3 0 5 0]`?

Comment: Your example result seems wrong - please make sure it is correct.  It seems to be mixing definitions.  Also referencing Cris Luengo, I also believe you are looking for `bitxor`.

Comment: Agree with all above.  Were you wanting `C=[0,1,0,1,0,1,0]`?  (w/ @rayryeng on inconsistency).  Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: sorry, the example is edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it likes the following:

```
C = (A ~= B);
```